# Missing DLL when run as script

Tags: php, batch-file, xampp

I'm trying to get a PHP script to run every 30 minutes on my server (Win XP SP3, xampp 1.7.3).
To do so I'm running the following script (update.cmd) using the MS task scheduler

```
SET PATH="C:\xampp\PHP"
start php.exe \htdocs\update_dashboard.php
```

I am using the oci8 php extension on my webserver, but when I run that script it gives me errors that php.exe can't find the necessary dll for the oci8 extension. I get the following errors:

`This application has failed to start because OCI.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem.`

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8.dll' - The specified module count not be found.

I know that the file is there and I don't get those errors when the php is run through apache, am I running the wrong copy of php.exe? Any ideas why not? Does my PATH have to be set differently? My Windows PATH includes:

`C:\instantclient_11_2;C:\oracle\ora92\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.3.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.1.8\bin;C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit 5\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Altiris\Software Virtualization Agent\`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem in a way by changing the script. It's now:

`C:\xampp\PHP\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\php_scripts\utils\update_dashboard.php`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I found this problem when I switch from php 5.3 non thread safe to php 5.3 thread safe on windows 7, and I ticked install everything

I fixed the issue by commenting out extension=php_oci8.dll, extension=php_oci8_11g.dll, extension=php_pdo_oci.dll in the php.ini

I also had issues with the sybase extension wanting a libcs.dll, which I solved by removing "extension=php_sybase_ct.dll"

eg

```
; at bottom of php.ini -->>
[PHP_BZ2]
extension=php_bz2.dll
[PHP_CURL]
extension=php_curl.dll
[PHP_ENCHANT]
extension=php_enchant.dll
[PHP_FILEINFO]
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
[PHP_GD2]
extension=php_gd2.dll
[PHP_GETTEXT]
extension=php_gettext.dll
[PHP_GMP]
extension=php_gmp.dll
[PHP_IMAP]
extension=php_imap.dll
[PHP_INTL]
extension=php_intl.dll
[PHP_LDAP]
extension=php_ldap.dll
[PHP_MBSTRING]
extension=php_mbstring.dll
[PHP_MYSQL]
extension=php_mysql.dll
[PHP_MYSQLI]
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;[PHP_OCI8]
;extension=php_oci8.dll
;[PHP_OCI8_11G]
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
[PHP_OPENSSL]
extension=php_openssl.dll
[PHP_PDO_MYSQL]
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;[PHP_PDO_OCI]
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
[PHP_PDO_ODBC]
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
[PHP_PDO_PGSQL]
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
[PHP_PDO_SQLITE]
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
[PHP_PGSQL]
extension=php_pgsql.dll
[PHP_SHMOP]
extension=php_shmop.dll
[PHP_SNMP]
extension=php_snmp.dll
[PHP_SOAP]
extension=php_soap.dll
[PHP_SOCKETS]
extension=php_sockets.dll
[PHP_SQLITE]
extension=php_sqlite.dll
[PHP_SQLITE3]
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;[PHP_SYBASE_CT]
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
[PHP_TIDY]
extension=php_tidy.dll
[PHP_XMLRPC]
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
[PHP_XSL]
extension=php_xsl.dll
[PHP_EXIF]
extension=php_exif.dll
```

Guessing if you need sybase and oracle database connections the standard clients install oci.dll and libcs.dll in the appropriate places, for everyone else who doesn't need to use these dbs just disable the php extensions, and it should run fine :)

Ant

Answer (score 1):

Check the php.ini file that php is using by running a phpinfo() from the command line, and look to see what extensions are enabled in that file. It's quite commopn for php to be set to use a different php.ini file when running from the command line; and xampp certainly uses a different php.ini file by default. You can also tell it what php.ini file to use with the -c switch

Comment: Thanks for the response. At the moment I can't even run a simple php file with 'phpinfo.php' because I can't get php started...

Answer (score 1):

I ran the php -m command. Turned out that my system's OCI.dll went either corrupt or missing. I recovered it by running sfc /scannow in the run box, rebooted, system reinstalled it, and it was up and running with my extensions now all working.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct that both `C:\instantclient_11_2` and `C:\oracle\ora92\bin` contain a `OCI.DLL`? Because of the order of the path you might load the wrong dll. When I read [Which OCI8 DLL to use in PHP 5.3](http://blogs.oracle.com/opal/2008/12/which_oci8_dll_to_use_in_php_5_1.html) you need a different line in the php.ini depending on the version of the oracle client. I currently have no access to a pc with oracle, so I cannot verify this.